# Why can't I access a variable from within my event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I'm making a project where I create the whole project (including the template) with C# on Visual Studio.

I've made the template and have just begun to work on the Events, I want to make an event MouseLeftButtonDown for a Canvas I created, this event will log the mouse position.

This is my code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private char tester;
        private Point down1;
        private Point up1;

        private void Grid1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RowDefinition row1 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition row2 = new RowDefinition();

            row1.Height = new GridLength(40);
            row2.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

            Grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(row1);
            Grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(row2);

            Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas();
            canvas1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Beige);
            Grid.SetRow(canvas1, 1);
            Grid1.Children.Add(canvas1);
            canvas1.MouseLeftButtonDown += new RoutedEventHandler(canvas1_MouseLeftButtonDown);
            canvas1.MouseLeftButtonUp += new RoutedEventHandler(canvas1_MouseLeftButtonUp);


            Button btnRect = new Button();
            btnRect.Content = "Rectangulo";
            btnRect.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
            btnRect.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            btnRect.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Grid.SetRow(btnRect, 0);
            Grid1.Children.Add(btnRect);
            //btnRect.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnRect_Click);

            Button btnEllip = new Button();
            btnEllip.Content = "Ellipse";
            btnEllip.Margin = new Thickness(75, 5, 5, 5);
            btnEllip.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            btnEllip.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Grid.SetRow(btnEllip, 0);
            Grid1.Children.Add(btnEllip);
            //btnEllip.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnEllip_Click);

        }
```

And this is my Event:

```
private void canvas1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                 down1 = e.GetPosition(canvas1); 
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried to do `down1 = e.GetPosition(canvas1);` but I'm getting an error on (canvas1); "The name canvas1 does not exist in the current context"

I've made a similar project without having to code the template, with no problems whatsoever..

Answer (score 2):

> but I'm getting an error on (canvas1);

That is because `canvas1` is a local variable of another method, not accessible inside `canvas1_MouseLeftButtonDown()`.

You can use:

```
 Canvas c = sender as Canvas;  // or Canvas c = (Canvas) sender;
 down1 = e.GetPosition(c);
```

Comment: I would use a cast over `as` so you can avoid the rather annoying `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Chaos: just to trade it in for an `InvalidCastException`? I don't think it matters here, I find `as` a little easier to read.

Comment: I prefer `InvalidCastException` because it gives you a bit more information. Just in case someone reuses the same handler for another control. *(I know this specific example it won't matter much but I still think it is good practice.)*

Comment: @Chaos: that is right but under the circumstances I would still use the more readable form.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `canvas1` as local variable inside the Grid1_Loaded method. Define it in the class as member variable instead and it should work.

Comment: Fantastic. Amazing how I fall for these things. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
down1 = e.GetPosition((Canvas)sender);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is canvas1 is a local variable in Grid1_Loaded. There is no way to access that variable outside that method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `canvas1` is not in scope. You could inline a simple lambda expression like this:

```
canvas1.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) => down1 = e.GetPosition(canvas1);
```